# how to get particular data displayed in textboxes using datagrid view

Tags: sql, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

I have created a form in which there are 4 labels teacher id ,teacher name and department and description along with respective textboxes. I have inserted the values in the database through ADD button (using insert query).I have taken datagrid view to display the data .

The problem is now i want that when iIselect one row of datagridview then it should display u=its data in respective text boxes. 
I have tried following code but not able write it properly.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SW-PC-20;Integrated security =SSPI;Initial catalog=institute");

con.Open();
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from teacher2", con);
SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(dr);
dr.Close();
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
     if (dr.HasRows)
                dr.Read();
         txtteacherid.Text = dr[0].ToString();
         txtteachername.Text = dr[1].ToString();
         txtdepartment.Text = dr[2].ToString();
         txtdescription.Text = dr[3].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

     if (e.RowIndex > -1)
                {
                    txtteacherid.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    txtteachername.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    txtdepartment.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                    txtdescription.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                }

    }
```